# haproxy https not work SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Tags: haproxy

Firefox:  SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
Chrome: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

haproxy.cfg

```
..........
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http 
frontend http-https-in 
bind    192.168.0.51:80 
bind    192.168.0.51:443

use_backend http_nginx_pool    if !{ ssl_fc }
use_backend https_nginx_pool   if { ssl_fc }


backend http_nginx_pool
    mode http
    server nginx1 192.168.0.36:80 check
    server nginx2 192.168.0.37:80 check

backend https_nginx_pool
    mode http
    server nginx1 192.168.0.36:443 check   
    server nginx2 192.168.0.37:443 check
```

*or recommend another program.
it is necessary that first requests go to 1 web server, and then to 2 web server if there is no site on 1*

backend https_nginx_pool
mode http
server nginx2 192.168.0.36:443 check **ssl verify none**

LOG ERROR
haproxy[551]: backend https_nginx_pool has no server available!

Broadcast message from systemd-journald@nginx (Thu 2023-07-27 14:19:23 UTC):

haproxy[551]: backend https_nginx_pool has no server available!

Comment: configure SSL in frontend on `bind 192.168.0.51:443 ssl crt /path/to/cert`